# send notification on click javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, notifications, query-string

So let's say I've got this code

```
<a href="www.yourdomain.com"><img src="http://www.image.com/image.jpg" /></a>
```

Super simple code. Now let's say that I give this code to my users as a B-B transaction. They can put this code ANYWHERE. Their site, ad space they bought, etc. Is there any sort of javascript code I can attach to it (or link to a php page and grab the referrer, then resend them perhaps?) so I can get some sort of notification?

So when people click on his version of the ad, I get some sort of notification?

So if I make it

```
<a href="www.MYdomain.com?theirdomain=www.blah.com" /><img></a>
```

I can grab "theirdomain" from the query string, and also forward them to "theirdomain". Easy enough.

**but now, now do I send "their domain" information to myself? What's the best way to have that collected?** < -- end root of the question, I suppose

Comment: What information from "their domain" are you wanting?

Comment: This question sounds like: how do I perform rudimentary XSS via JavaScript injection.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose one of your clients is www.foo.com.

You can give them this to place on their website:

`<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/click_ad.php?domain=foo.com"><img src="..." /></a>`

On your website, you'll want to include a click_ad.php file which inserts a value into your database stating that foo.com has had a user click on their version of the ad. You can find out how to do this here:

**Reference**: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

I would suggest you use one database table for the domains (and link them to an ID) and then another for the clicks (linking the domain IDs with the click amounts).

Comment: All good answers - but this is what I needed. I needed to know HOW to do it - that link provides me with what I need - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Typically, this is done by bouncing it off your own server, no JS required.

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/track?url=www.yourdomain.com">
  Go to yourdomain.com!
</a>
```

`http://mydomain.com/track` is then responsible for 2 things:

- Logging the click in your database, increasing a click count, creating a click record, whatever
- Responding with a 301 Redirect to the desired URL.

The user that clicked is none the wiser this happens, because your server sends no renderable content and it should respond quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Link:

```
<a href="www.MYdomain.com/ad.php?url=www.blah.com" /><img></a>
```

`ad.php`:

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $redirectURL = $_GET['url'];

    // do your stuff here

    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header("Location: $redirectURL");
}
```

The request comes to your server, you read the query string parameter `url` and do whatever you need, and then redirect to the destination url.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things you can save when someone visits your website over a link. Check php's `$_SERVER` variable

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

For you the `HTTP_REFERER` part might be very interesting. But do not put too much trust in it as it is not always set or can be set manually.

Apart from that I agree with @Alex Wayne. You can/should set up a tracking url that just collects information and redirects (use 301!) to the target page without the user noticing.

The information that you gather, you can store in a database, e.g. mysql or text file or send an email or whatever you feel like suits you best.